# Locally Finite Refinement

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that second-countable topological space $M$ has locally finite refinement $\{U_\alpha\}$ (i.e. such that each point in $M$ possesses a neighbourhood that intersects only a finite number of $U_\alpha$) of any open cover?

Comment: Every space has finite covers. Do you mean to ask whether every open cover of a second countable space has a locally finite open refinement?

Comment: @Daniel, yes of course!

Comment: It is true if the space is regular.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking if every second countable space is paracompact and the answer to this general question is no. Any countably infinite set with the [particular point topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology) will be second countable but non-paracompact.

As Stefan suggests with the added assumption of regularity a second countable space becomes metrizable and therefore is paracompact.